# Linking column data between sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Have an issue where I'm trying to create a dynamic link between two columns separated into two different worksheets. What is currently happening is we have an instrument that spits data into a worksheet we'll just label it TData. There is another worksheet that we have we can call it Sheet1.

In Tdata we're only looking for the results in column A(we can call it the data) and results in column C(the test data). I'm trying to make it so whenever the instrument populate these fields in Tdata that they also get populated whatever active cell the user currently has their mouse over which is usually column D which corresponds to test data and E for the date.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim TestData As String
Dim Datee As String


Sheets("TData").Select
TestData = Range("C5").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

ActiveWorkbook.Save


End Sub
```

Is what I currently have. The Test data starts at C5 because of the format of the information the instrument spits out. The amount of rows depends on how many measurements a technician get's through the day. In addition this particular code uses a command button. I'd prefer not to have that button and just have it as a dynamic sort of link between the two sheets but if a button is necessary I'm not going to fight against it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like `TData` and `Sheet1` are in the same workbook. Is there any reason not to use formulas instead?

Comment: Exactly how does the test data get into the workbook?

Comment: Through an instrument. There is a macro based program that polls the instrument for the data.

Comment: So I updated this a bit.